# Проблема с чтением и выводом элементов коллекции с помощью цикла foreach

Tags: java, циклы, коллекции, foreach

Ситуация следующая:

`Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);`
Здесь мы вводим значения диапазона поиска аудикомпозиций по длине.

```
        System.out.println("Введите начальное значние диапазона и нажмите Enter (пример: 1,11):");
        double startValue = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Введите итоговое значание диапазона и нажмите Enter (пример: 1,11):");
        double finalValue = input.nextDouble();
```

У нас есть `LinkedList`, состоящий из объектов, у которых есть поле `trackLength`, пример:
`id: 1, name: "John Lennon - Imagine", trackLength: 3.01;`
`id: 2, name: "Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody", trackLength: 5.55;`
`id: 3, name: "Abba - Dancing Queen", trackLength: 3.52;`

Мне нужно исключить ввод одинаковых значений, при условии, что данные значения не равны `trackLength` в моем листе.

У меня есть следующий код:

```
        for (Track allTracks : wholeMixTape) {
            double length = allTracks.getTrackLength();
            if (startValue == finalValue & startValue != length & length != finalValue) {
                System.out.println("error");
            } else  if (startValue <= length & length <= finalValue | startValue <= length & length <= finalValue & startValue == finalValue){
                System.out.println(allTracks);
            }
        }
```

Данный код работает не так, как было задумано мною. При вводе `startValue=5` и `finalValue=5`, в консоль выводится 3 сообщения `error`.

```
error  
error  
error
```

Если же мы вводим существующие значение `5,55`, то получим следующий вывод:

```
error  
2. Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody / 5,55  
error
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы выводилось найденное значение, либо же вывести `error` ровно 1 раз.

Comment: добавь флаг, что ошибка уже напечатана. Взводи его при первой ошибке и потом проверяй и больше не печатай. Ну и вообще, странный поиск. Везде проверяешь на точное значение, а не на попадание в интервал.

Comment: Я описал конкретный случай в общих чертах, вдруг пользователь введет два одинаковых значения, то ему должно упасть сообщение, что данные введены некорректно...

Comment: А зачем проверять явно некорректное соотношение `startValue == finalValue` _в цикле_?  Это условие срабатывает каждый раз, поэтому его следует проверять раньше, _до цикла_.  Также нужно обратить внимание на использование _побитовых_ операций `&` `|` в `if`, где должны быть логические `&&` и `||`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из вашего ТЗ, я подготовил решение для вас.

```
    boolean check = true;
    for (Track allTracks : wholeMixTape) {
      double length = allTracks.getTrackLength();
      if (startValue <= length & length <= finalValue) {
        check = false;
        System.out.println(allTracks);
      }
    }
    if(check) 
      System.out.println("error");
```

Немного дополнив свой ответ, могу подсказать посмотреть в сторону `Stream API`

```
long size = wholeMixTape.stream()
        .filter(track -> startValue <= track.getTrackLength() & track.getTrackLength() <= finalValue)
        .peek(track -> System.out.println(track))
        .count();
if (size <= 0)
   System.out.println("error");
```